# Probabilities in Runtime analysis?

Tags: algorithm, hash

This is a homework question and I am terribly confused regarding it's correct approach.

There exists a hash table of **m slots**. We assume **Simple Uniform Hashing assumption** (SUHA).

***We perform n insert operations but all n elements map to slot 0. (This is not likely, but possible).***

Now the question asks to search for a random key 'x' whose hash may or may not exist in the table. *What is the upper bound on runtime for search to complete?*

***This is my approach:***

Since we assume SUHA, the Probability of a key to hash to a slot is 1/m. If key indeed hashes to slot 0 then search takes O(n) time otherwise it takes O(m-1) time. By this logic, would the solution be [1/m]*O(n)+[(m-1)/m]*O(m-1) which simplifies to O(n/m + [(m-1)^2]/m).

**1. Can probabilities be multiplied in this manner to asymptotic runtimes?**

**2. Would probably even play a role in determining the runtime?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're thinking about this wrong. Probability should not be factored. Since the question is asking for the upper bound, translate that question to, *What is the worst case scenario?*

The worst case scenario is if x hashes to 0 like every previous hash before it. Now imagine x was the last element hashed. You would have to traverse the possible locations until you find the element you're looking for, depending on the collision resolution. This would make it O(n) since it's depending on the number of n previous hashes as illustrated in the problem.

The best case scenario just to say, is if x did not hash to 0. Since computing the hash is O(1), once you hash to a key, it's either there or not, another O(1) operation making it overall, O(1) operation.

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure if probability would act as a factor. In that case won't the runtime just be n+(m-1)? (time to look through the chain and to look through the remaining slots)

Comment: No. Why would you need to look through all the remaining slots ? Maps have collision resolution which define how to store a value if it hashes to a location a previous value exists. So imagine if this used a single linked list for example where each slot stores a linked list and collions result in the value being appended to the end of the list. Worst case on your search, is a linked list of length n so you just need to search through n items

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. If I modify my question and say that n/2 elements map to slot 0 and n/2 elements map to slot 1, would the answer still remain the same? I am really trying to think of a situation where probability plays a role!

Comment: That would still be worse case O(n). If you're searching for a value, you're gonna hash it and look at the slot the hash computes. There are two scenarios in your example, one where 0 elements already exists so O(1) and one where n/2 elements exist, which mean you only need to search through n/2 elements making it O(n). Is there something more concrete I can provide to help with how you're thinking ?

Comment: No, now it makes sense. I guess I was forcing myself to think about probabilities. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Upper bound means worst case.

When you take the probability as '1/m', you are calculating the average case.

You may now try the question without looking below as I'm going to write the solution:

---

---

---

---

---

The worst case would be when:

- The key will hash to the same slot where all the inserts fell.

In that case, you will have to go through all the elements of that slot, leading to a running time of O(n).

Comment: Isn't it so that probability comes into play when a key is being hashed. Worst case analysis comes into play when an already hashed value is to be searched for (which may be anywhere)? That is, worst case analysis is performed after hashing is complete?

Comment: The probability for a key to hash to a slot is irrelevant. In a map with m slots, a key hashes to the same value always. A hash is just a constant operation. Therefore, you don't need to search everywhere for the key you're looking for, just the slot the key hashes to, or the possible locations if a collision occurred making the worst case search O(n).

Comment: @Janmajay: Yes, the probability of hash is '1/m'. Worst case analysis means assuming that worst _will_ happen. The worst for this is when the hashed index value turns out to be the one where all the inserted values are lying.